# É recomendado o uso de constantes pra configurações de um projeto em PHP?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

É muito comum de ver constantes em um arquivo de configurações num projeto PHP, porém eu gostaria de saber se essa é realmente a melhor prática, pois penso que se eu armazenar a senha de um banco de dados em um arquivo *config.php* ela poderá ser utilizada em qualquer lugar, ou seja, acessível em todo meu projeto, não sei se isso iria se encaixar no padrão (ou anti-padrão) "God Object", mas seriam as constantes a melhor solução para este tipo de problema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De todos os frameworks PHP que trabalhei até hoje, nenhum deles utilizaram constantes para guardar dados de conexão com banco de dados (e outras coisas, por exemplo).

Costumo ver essa utilização de constantes em Bibliotecas mais antigas.

No `CakePHP 2`, era utilizado constantes para configuração de banco de dados, porém a mesma ficava dentro de uma classe.

Exemplo:

```
class DB_CONFIG
{
    const HOST = 'nome_do_host';
    ...
}
```

No `Laravel 4 e 5`, usa-se um arquivo de configuração que retorna um `array` com os dados de conexão, sendo lido apenas pelo local onde o mesmo é incluído.

O `Symfony 2` utiliza `yaml` por padrão, podendo também ser utilizadas outras opções.

Eu não recomendaria o uso de constantes, a não ser que fosse num namespace específico ou numa classe, como se faz no `Cakephp 2`.

Vale lembrar também que, independente das formas que destaquei e idependente de usar constante ou não, todos os destacados acima foram unânimes numa coisa: O local de configuração é separado e fácil de encontrar. Isso melhora a vida do programador, quando o mesmo tem que configurar a aplicação. Pois é comum pessoas misturarem script para configuração e script de saída de dados, o que gera uma grande confusão.

No final, o que pode importar é mais a organização do que o próprio meio onde os dados são guardados.

Vale lembrar que, nas versões do `PHP 5.6 >=`, podemos utilizar `array` em constantes. Assim, fica mais fácil utilizar, do que ficar usando prefixos para constantes.

Exemplo PHP Atualmente:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'SENHA');
```

Exmeplo PHP 5.6 >:

```
define('DB', [
    'HOST' => 'localhost',
    'USER' => 'username',
    'PASSWORD' => 'SENHA'
]);
```

OU

```
const DB = [ 'HOST' => 'localhost', ...];
```

## Outras formas

No PHP também é possível usar arquivos `ini` e `json`.

No caso do `json`:

config.json

```
   {
     "DB": {
         "HOST" : 'localhost'
     }
   }
```

Carregando o JSON:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'));
```

Exemplo ini:

config.ini

```
[DB]
HOST=localhost
PASSWORD=senha
```

No PHP:

```
parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
```

**Nota**: Esses dois últimos casos, devem ser separados em diretórios não acessíveis ao cliente, uma vez que o navegador pode ler seu conteúdo como texto, caso seja listado

Comment: Muito interessante essa solução, mas no caso de eu utilizar um INI por exemplo, seria bom eu ter uma classe (model) apenas para ler e trazer essa informação quando for necessária, correto?

Comment: Também é possível! Seria mais interessante se esse model detectasse on índice `[DB]` e `[DB_LOCAL]`, pra você já configurar uma vez só os dados de conexão em produção (como no Laravel). Daí você só precisa informar para sua aplicação se está em produção ou  local para ela realizar a troca dos dados de conexão automaticamente

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada no Laravel, embora eu queira evitar o uso de frameworks pois eu estou aprendendo e desenvolvendo um CMS do zero (apenas pra estudo), acho que aprender com eles vai ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 5):

Acho que isto não pode ser considerado [*god object*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415961/101), não me parece sequer ser um objeto, talvez queria falar de outra coisa.

Esta não é a melhor prática mas é muito praticada sem causar grandes problemas na prática. Aí depende de quanto precisa ter segurança do acesso aos dados. Obviamente com a senha exposta, outras pessoas que tenham acesso ao servidor, terão acesso ao banco, mas provavelmente o banco também não estará criptografado, então faz pouca diferença.

Se precisa da segurança de fato a autenticação não pode ser feita desta forma, precisaria que o acesso ao banco fosse feito apenas com senha passada pelo usuário de forma segura. O que é inviável no caso do usuário ser anônimo. Então poderia usar uma senha armazenada em algum lugar mas criptografada. Isto não quer dizer que a segurança seja absoluta.

Não faz a menor diferença ser constante ou estar armazenada de outra forma. Não vai mudar nada colocar em outra forma, constantes devem ser evitadas, mas algumas que claramente tem função global, não tem problemas.

Answer (score 5):

A **constante** não é uma **recomendação para usar em configurações**, é uma forma de manter um dado constante em todo o seu projeto, que será usado repetidamente em vários lugares.

Em várias situações, podemos ter constantes com dados que serão mantidos em todo o seu projeto, como os dois exemplos abaixo:

```
//resumo da constante do php de diretório    
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
//caminho físico da aplicação
define('APPLICATION_PATH', '..' . DS . dirname(__DIR__) . DS);
```

O que o torna diferente, é a facilidade de manutenção "manual" (caso seja necessário, o que dificilmente deverá ser).

Uma das recomendações de uso está na sua agregação de eventos definidos com **setEnv**, que podem estar definindo parâmetros ao ambiente de desenvolvimento. Como o Zend Framework já utiliza na virtualização de host:

**yourproject.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName yourproject.local
     DocumentRoot /var/www/YourProject/public
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory /var/www/YourProject/publicc>
          DirectoryIndex index.php
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**PHP**

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') ||
define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?
getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

Ou seja, quando utilizar constante, parta do princípio de que será algo que não irá mudar (**nunca? quem sabe...**).

**Em suma:** constante é o que o próprio nome e seu comportamento diz, algo constante, que não muda. Se na sua aplicação tiver algo dessa maneira, **use**, para não ter que destroçar caroços mais tarde de coisas que não precisam mudar nunca.

Exemplo de uso de constante com classe:

```
class AppPath
{
   const APPLICATION_PATH = "/path/app/";

   public function __construct()
   {
       echo self::APPLICATION_PATH;
   }
}

//instanciando a classe, o construtor retornará a constante
return new AppPath();
```

Comment: Gostei da sua solução, e por exemplo, caso eu precise usar uma constante como APPLICATION_PATH, eu posso usar diretamente em uma classe ou devo injeta-la através de parâmetros? Obrigado.

Comment: O uso de constante global, pode ser feito em uma classe abstrata (não instancia), ou em um arquivo bootstrap ou autoload de uma aplicação mvc fora da classe, já que o mesmo estará em todo o projeto. Também pode usar dentro de classes de controle ou entidade, porém ela só terá uso dentro da mesma, a menos que tenha uma herança atribuída para as demais classes.

Comment: Só um toque: O último exemplo não funciona, pois o `__construct` não retorna valores em PHP

Comment: Verdade, esqueci deste detalhe, obrigado @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 4):

Depende muito do tipo de configuração que você quer armazenar e da arquitetura do seu sistema. Por exemplo, configurações que são gerenciadas por usuário, por exemplo: cor, tamanho, estilo, layout e etc seria preferível que não armazenasse em constantes, porque como o próprio nome já diz, são constantes e sendo assim deveriam permanecer com um unico valor a partir do momento em que são setadas.

No entanto, se o seu sistema tem um login unico e você precisa fazer uso da senha do cliente, eu não vejo problema em criar uma constante com a senha. Desde que o valor dela não se altere durante a execução do programa.

Answer (score 4):

Senhas e dados de acesso eu já prefiro [encapsular](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Objetos/Encapsulamento) e apenas minha classe de conexão/ou afins ter acesso a esses dados. Acho que qualquer forma de variável acessível demais compromete de alguma forma a segurança da sua aplicação.

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei quando vi o código fonte do Wordpress, logo no início para facilitar a configuração do usuário você digita a senha do banco de dados em uma constante (define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here'); mas esses dias brincando com umas funções em um plugin eu vi que simplesmente qualquer um consegue ter acesso a constante com a senha, o que seria muito inseguro, vendo a vasta gama de plugins que o Wordpress oferece e a facilidade que é para se publicar um. É claro que esse é um caso bem específico, mas é uma dúvida que eu sempre tive em meus projetos.

Answer (score 4):

Constantes são usadas como pedaços de informação reaproveitáveis de formal (geralmente) global e imutável, ou seja, não muda.

No caso de criar uma constante para senha do seu banco dados é altamente recomendável que ela seja criptografada antes da definição.

Quando ao God object basicamente é uma classe ou objeto que funciona como repositório de funções, classe/objeto tem mais de uma responsabilidade.

Comment: Particularmente, @rray, eu detesto contantes! Ficar lembrando dos prefixos e nomes é chato! Por exemplo, as constantes que são flag da `filter_var`. Pra mim, isso dificulta a situação! Mas há casos onde seu uso é bem aplicável.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters,  constantes não precisam de prefixos :P, ninguém reclama do `TB_`(não sou fã de prefixos). Elas  também são uma forma de tornar acessível uma informação de maneira única como por exemplo criar uma constante para rebecer o valor em segundos de uma hora ou do dia, é muito isso do que jogar em variáveis locais avulsa. Só para não perder a piada, `define('MUDANÇA', true);` :D

Comment: se você não usar prefixo, é pior ainda. Aí você vai bagunçar toda a bagaça. Eu preferiria usar um namespace, ou até mesmo um array num arquivo de configuração com o famoso `return array(...)`;

Comment: @WallaceMaxters você não vai precisar de tantas constantes assim :P. Concordo que é melhor jogar essas informações em arquivo a parte, as vezes a aplicação php tem o código ofuscado ou 'fechado', ai vai alterar a linha de configuração do banco como sem gerar um novo build?

Comment: Gostei da definição que você deu para sua resposta, apenas me intrometendo na conversa, como eu usaria uma senha criptografada sendo que ela teria que ser lida por alguma classe? E outra pergunta em particular, vocês teriam algum artigo bom para me indicar sobre namespaces em PHP? Eu tentei utilizar porém fiquei bem confuso.

Comment: Tem alguma informação incorreta na resposta? posso corrigir.

Answer (score 3):

Melhor centralizar seus dados em um arquivo de configuração.

Se tu vai usar com define, ou se tu vai usar um .env (dotEnv), não faz muita diferença.

Só não deixe ele fixo no código, pois dificulta a manutenção.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve utilizar as constantes apenas para guardar informações que **não mudam**  e devem ficar acessíveis **em qualquer lugar do projeto**.

Em todos os demais casos, recomendo que utilize um arquivo de configuração acessível através de uma classe de configuração

Exemplo: `Config::get( 'databases.main' )`.