# $GLOBALS para armazenar configurações?

Tags: php, engenharia-de-software, configuração, variáveis-globais

Oi, na semana passada eu perguntei qual era a melhor forma de [armazenar e ler configurações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101076/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-de-armazenar-e-ler-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es) para um website, e consegui 2 respostas. Dessas duas respostas, houve muitas especulações, mas nenhuma explicava realmente porquê eu deveria usar um tipo e não o outro, apenas diziam que era melhor fazer daquela forma. Pelo contrário eu agradeço a ajuda que o pessoal deu lá, e não quis parecer mal educada. Por exemplo na primeira resposta, dizia exclusivamente para - *manter a configuração exclusiva a acesso público* - aí eu bloquei e me perguntei, se era acesso físico ou as propriedades que coloquei nesse ficheiro ?

Por outro lado, um usuário ainda comentou o seguinte sobre os diferentes tipos de configurações:

> Não vejo uma questão de segurança e sim mais questão de praticidade para eventuais alterações. Sim no meu caso uso mais por praticidade. Acredito que esse tipo de necessidade surgiu para programas compilados, para não ter necessidade para compilar o programa td vez que muda a configuração do banco de dados (senha, usuario, endereço do servidor, etc). **@Skywalker**

Eu investiguei fundo, e encontrei uma resposta nesse [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666728/load-website-configuration-from-json-or-php-file), com algumas comparações significativas, ajudou bastante com algumas dúvidas que eu tinha, mas não todas.

Depois de muita leitura e análises, eu decidi manter a configuração em um ficheiro `.php`, mas usando uma variável `global` para conseguir ler elas com mais facilidade.

```
$GLOBALS['configuracao'] = array();
```

Aí eu posso ler ela em qualquer sítio dentro do meu script.

**O que tenho ?**

- Uma classe para ler essas configurações
- Uma ou mais classes que dependem dessas configurações, por isso elas podem ser usadas muitas vezes (ex.: `mysql`,`sessoes`,`cookies` e outros).

**Como uso ?**

- Estou usando `OOP` para tornar um site antigo mais fácil de configurar e modificar.
- A minha classe de leitura, só usa esses valores se eu não injetar outra configuração.
- O método que uso para retornar esse valor é estático.

> **Por ela se tratar de uma variável `global` não tem problema se armazenar as minhas configurações nela ? E como especificamente eu coloco meus dados de configuração fora do alcance público ?**

Comment: Você já fez isto? Não sei se resolve como está pensando. Eu preciso sair mas respondo quando voltar.

Comment: Já fiz a parte da configuração, mas não sei se deixo desse jeito, porque é uma variável global.

Comment: Isso dá um certo medo pois vai carregar na variável global todas as configurações e muitos desses dados vc acaba não usando todos eles numa única página. Entende? EStaria apenas consumindo memória. O seu aplicativo fica pesado e isso pesa no bolso também pois precisará de servidores mais potentes, que custam mais. Pensem em algo enxuto que poupe recursos. Quanto mais conseguir fazer com menos recursos, é melhor.

Comment: A duração de uma página PHP é tão curta que a alocação e desalocação em blocos acaba sendo até mais eficiente. Em PHP, quanto mais direto se vai ao ponto, maior o aproveitamento de recursos da máquina. Quase todas as teorias acadêmicas se dão melhor nas linguagens de programação do que nas de script, que é o caso do PHP (que nem loop principal é comum, muito menos persistência de estruturas de dados na memória). Neste caso, pode se tranquilizar, que global nao vai atrapalhar em nada. Até porque, internamente, uma classe é alocada como global. Imagine os membros dela como se fosse um array.

Comment: Obrigada pelo comentário @Bacco.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em princípio não há problema em fazer isto, sempre digo, desde que saiba o que está fazendo. Tenha em mente que isto precisará sempre ser incluído nos *scripts* sempre que necessário.

A tal da engenharia de software não recomenda o uso de variáveis globais, é uma boa recomendação, mas não é algo mandatório. Precisamos entender porque existe esta recomendação, para isto já existe uma [pergunta aqui que explica o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Sem saber porque é problemático realmente fica difícil tomar decisões, para um lado ou outro. A AP está mais que certa em perguntar quando tem dúvidas.

## PHP

Já adianto, se quer aplicar as melhores técnicas de engenharia de software não use PHP. Esta não é uma linguagem que incentiva isto, ela é bem pragmática e incentiva a praticidade e flexibilidade de codificação. Claro que não estou falando para jogar tudo no lixo e ignorar tudo o que esta disciplina nos ensina, só digo que o seu uso em PHP deve ser balanceado para alcançar os objetivos da linguagem. Nem tão pouco estou dizendo que não dá para aplicar as melhores técnicas de engenharia em PHP, sSó não é o maior trunfo dela, ela brilha em outros pontos.

Faça como o Facebook, mude de linguagem quando tem um código muito complexo.

Em base de código muito grande que será usada por muito tempo, por equipes, e que há uma metodologia aplicada que exige certa disciplina, como a criação e execução de testes estruturados, faz muito sentido evitar - ênfase para o "evitar" - não só o estado global, também o escopo global.

Mas estamos falando de *scripts* PHP onde a base de código costuma ser pequena, para uso pontual e feito por poucas pessoas, em geral apenas uma. E poucas pessoas usam metodologias formais nestes sites, a maioria nem tem ideia de como fazer testes formais, então alguns motivos para evitar estas variáveis vão sumindo.

Paranoias com consumo de memória, vazamentos de dados ou mesmo abstração não fazem muito sentido em algo tão efêmero.

Ah, não confunda volume de código com volume de dados. PHP aguenta bem volume de dados grandes, mas não é tão fácil trabalhar com volume de código. Por sorte é uma linguagem aplicada na web que roda pequenos *scripts* e não um volume de código enorme simultaneamente. O site é um conjunto de pequenas aplicações que rodam de forma independente, não é um executável monolítico, não é todo interdependente. Aqui o PHP brilha.

Claro que os sites que lidam com grandes volumes de dados possuem código mais simples, são mais concretos e menos abstratos. Eles evitam OOP. Como ocorre neste site que está usando agora. Afinal OOP não é bala de prata, ele auxilia em circunstâncias específicas. Em mãos erradas pode até atrapalhar.

## A solução é amplamente usada

Note que a variável `$GLOBALS` já existe. Serão criadas entradas para ela. Então já há um certo escopo. Seria ruim criar variáveis livres porque elas poderiam se confundir com as variáveis locais, isto realmente é algo ruim.

Outra técnica usada é criar uma variável global própria de configuração, assim apenas uma pode ser confundir com as locais, isto bem documentando não causará problemas. Assim como todo programador PHP sabe que não pode usar uma variável chamada `$GLOBALS`, ou `$_POST`, etc. Basta convencionar e documentar. Não causa problemas de escopo.

De uma certa forma isto está sendo feito criando um nível de variável dentro de `$GLOBALS`. Pelo que entendi não serão criadas várias entradas nesta variável e sim várias entradas na entrada `configuracoes` que foi criada em `$GLOBALS`. Ótima técnica para evitar conflitos.

## Os problemas que podem acontecer

A configuração poderá ter mais que uma instância um dia? Acho que que não.

Vai executar testes formais? Duvido. Mesmo que seja feito, precisará ser "*mockado*"? Mesmo que precise, tem como resolver isto facilmente.

Vai ter concorrência? Em *scripts* PHP não costuma ter. Se tiver, haverá escrita nas configurações? Não parece. Mesmo que tenha, a escrita precisa ocorrer no arquivo, o que dá para fazer travamento fácil.

Isto será usado no lugar de passagem de parâmetros para transportar dados variáveis por toda a aplicação? Parece que não.

## O dado é global

É fato que este é um dado que é inerentemente global, ele é necessário globalmente.

Qualquer outra alternativa só será uma forma mais complicada de deixar isto global. As soluções que podem ser apresentadas só encapsularão os dados de outra forma, mas o acesso se dará de forma global. Ou vão inventar uma forma que sequer atende as reais necessidades desta característica do software.

Note que na pergunta *linkada* acima mostra que há casos para seu uso, diversos softwares usam, os mais conhecidos em PHP usam sem problemas, vários bem grandes, alguns fazem pior.

Por exemplo, o WordPress usa constantes que são globais. Mas é pior porque cria vários símbolos globais. Em geral não causa maiores problemas, o WordPress fez de um jeito adequado e documentou isto. Mas se não souber o que está fazendo pode gerar um caos de escopo. Claro que até programadores bem inexperientes conseguem fazer certo. Mas não seria melhor se não criar nenhum símbolo global, colocar tudo em algo que já existe na linguagem? Afinal a linguagem tem seus defeitos mas ela criou o `$GLOBALS` por ele ser útil, não é para ser deixado de lado por uma solução pior.

## Quais alternativas?

Ficar lendo um arquivo toda hora? Muito pior.

Colocar em uma classe para acesso global? Que no fundo, em PHP, funciona de forma análoga ao `$GLOBALS`. Sim, o PHP mantém todas classes em uma tabela global de símbolos e seus membros funcionam como as entradas de um *array* associativo. É só uma questão de sintaxe, não muda a semântica. Quem conhece o funcionamento interno do PHP sabe disto.

Qual a vantagem disto em softwares simples que sequer serão testados formalmente?

Não existe milagre.

Eu consigo fazer diversas críticas conceituais para usar esta forma, mas nenhuma será pragmática, nenhuma levará em consideração a real forma como o software provavelmente está sendo desenvolvido.

## Consumo de servidores

E não se preocupe com desempenho ou consumo de memória, ele não será pior que as alternativas. E mesmo que fosse, será insignificante. E mais, quem precisa de desempenho e economia de memória usa outra linguagem. O PHP não preza pela economia de servidores, ele preza pela economia de desenvolvimento. O que alguns programadores subvertem criando softwares caros de desenvolver e caros para rodar do mesmo jeito.

Se o software estiver muito pesado e tiver uma quantidade absurda de configurações, pode-se criar uma granularidade maior. Mas se o software está tão pesado assim, aí tem que repensar tudo, aí melhores técnicas de engenharia são necessárias, usar uma linguagem mais adequada será necessário.

Não se esqueça que este `$GLOBALS` que está em um arquivo deverá ser carregado com `#include`. Então você pode ter vários arquivos cada um com uma parte das configurações. Você carrega só o que precisa. Esta é a natureza de uma linguagem de *script*, esta é sua vantagem.

Mas, sinceramente, o ganho é ínfimo. Quem conhece o funcionamento do ambiente de execução do PHP sabe que não fará diferença alguma. Provavelmente nem dará para mensurar ganho, e mesmo que dê, ficará só na medida, não em ganho na prática, é uma micro otimização tola.

## Segurança

Isto provavelmente está em um arquivo `.php` que já deve estar protegido contra acesso externo, certo? Se está, então já está protegido. Arquivos com esta extensão costumam só poder ser executados pelo mecanismo do PHP e não acessado diretamente. Só precisa tomar o cuidado de não deixá-lo com permissão de escrita. O que eventualmente pode ser necessário em alguns tipos de softwares (não nos que já são personalizados) que permitem os usuários mudarem as configurações pela *web*. Aí outros cuidados precisam ser tomados. Não parece ser o caso.

## Conclusão

Não faça uma rodovia de 6 pistas para atender uma necessidade vicinal.

Ainda bem, a AP já concluiu que um arquivo INI não é uma boa. A melhor opção é colocar em um arquivo fonte do PHP. A melhor opção é colocar em uma coleção de dados. Classes deveriam ser imutáveis, então um *array* é a solução. Você deve criar um novo ou usar um já existente e documentado? Assim fica fácil decidir pelo `$GLOBALS`. A AP mostra que sabe pesquisar e fazer uma análise apurada, embora nestes caso a opção seja bastante óbvia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora que eu vi que a pergunta foi modificada. Tome cuidado com isto porque pode invalidar respostas. A min ha mesmo seria diferente com a atual composição da pergunta. Eu acho que esta pergunta ficou comprometida. O ideal seria ter colocado estas alterações em outra pergunta com mais detalhes, provavelmente colocando o código para pedir ajuda de como deve tratar as configurações. Isto já começa fugir o intuito original da pergunta. Embora eu acho que pela edição, já está comprando a ideia da complicação. Se é pra complicar, complique de vez.

Comment: Eu escolhi essa resposta porque parece que mais ninguém vai responder ou mesmo editar, e essa talvez seja a única que ainda esteja dentro do contexto.

Comment: Deu para entender que apesar do nome de global esta variável só existe se ela for carregada no momento da execução do *script* e ela não está viva naturalmente por todo o site? Em PHP o global é muito restrito, então estas técnicas de organização não fazem muito sentido.

Comment: O global que falo é que ela é acessível mesmo dentro de funções ou em classes, basta que eu coloque um require ou include do ficheiro onde defini os meus dados. Vou criar outra pergunta explicando como chegam os valores e como consigo acesso a eles.

Comment: coloquei ela aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102652/vari%c3%a1vel-global-personalizada

Answer (score 4):

Isso pode variar de acordo com o seu projeto e com certeza sempre irá gerar uma boa discussão.

Se você está programando de forma estrutural, há outras formas de se fazer, como constantes ou vetores em variáveis comuns (ver [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98960/%C3%89-recomendado-o-uso-de-constantes-pra-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-projeto-em-php)), porém é bem mais trabalhoso você esconder isso quando está fazendo dessa forma, sem falar que constantes tem um "peso" a mais na sua aplicação em comparação à outras variáveis.

De certa forma eu pessoalmente não usaria `$GLOBALS` para configurações pelo fato de que você tem que pensar em seu projeto sempre com a possibilidade de expandir e dar manutenção futuramente, independente de qual linguagem esteja usando e de qual tamanho seja sua aplicação.

Caso você esteja trabalhando orientado à objetos, você pode se aproveitar do encapsulamento para resolver esse problema, onde você irá possuir uma classe que irá ler e definir as configurações, e através da [injeção de dependência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) irá passar esses valores somente para onde você quer.

Agora vamos as suas perguntas.

**Por ela se tratar de uma variável global não tem problema se armazenar as minhas configurações nela ?**

Novamente eu afirmo que depende do que você precisa. Você não quer que os outros vejam essas configurações, mas quem iria ver essas configurações?

Se você trabalha com um script pequeno onde suas senhas ficam salvas em um arquivo, é bem provável que alguém possa simplesmente abrir o arquivo e ver essas configurações da mesma forma, tal como dar um `var_dump()` na variável e ver tudo, porém em relação ao usuário, se não está no script e não possui vulnerabilidades que possam revelar o conteúdo dessa variável, então não teria problema algum.

**E como especificamente eu coloco meus dados de configuração fora do alcance público ?**

Se você trabalha em um **projeto maior**, onde tem pessoas que são responsáveis somente pela parte do Layout e elas não tem que saber absolutamente nada do que se passa "por trás" do projeto, você poderia estar trabalhando com classes, assim poderia possuir uma instância de uma classe de configurações que iria passar os valores somente para onde fosse necessário, o que não é o caso do layout, que irá receber tudo "processado" e limpo, só fará a exibição do conteúdo gerado.

**Exemplo:** Temos uma classe de configuração e uma classe de banco de dados, você precisa passar as configurações para o banco de dados, veja as classes *de forma extremamente simples apenas para o aprendizado*.

```
class config
{
    private $cfg;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Aqui será a forma que você irá fazer a leitura de suas configs para a variável $this->cfg;
    }
    
    public function get($sessao,$parametro)
    {
        return $this->cfg[$sessao][$parametro];
    }
}
```

Vamos supor que você precisa pegar as configurações para obter o usuário do banco de dados.

```
class database_mysql
{
    private $cfg
    private $usuario
    
    public function __construct(config $cfg)
    {
        $this->cfg = $cfg;
    }
    
    public function ler_usuario()
    {
        $this->usuario = $this->cfg->get['database','usuario'];
    }
}
```

Então é aí então que a injeção de dependência é realizada.

```
$minha_config = new config();
$meu_db = new database_mysql($minha_config);
```

Assim, só poderá ter acesso as configurações determinados objetos que tiverem o acesso à classe `config`, e você injeta essa dependência dentro do objeto que precisar.

## Vale apena complicar?

Isso vai complicar significativamente o seu projeto, daí cabe a você avaliar se realmente precisa disso. Qualquer projeto que eu faça eu sempre penso na possibilidade de dar manutenção e expandir um dia, é muito melhor você gastar mais tempo e trabalho para fazer algo bem feito do que pensar "isso é pequeno demais pra me preocupar com isso", pra quando surgir uma manutenção e você ter que mudar todo seu sistema, a não ser que realmente não tenha absolutamente nenhuma necessidade de complicar.

**É completamente opcional trabalhar orientado à objeto em PHP, porém pense nas vantagens que você pode ter quando precisar dar uma manutenção ou expandir seu projeto.**

> “O desenvolvedor está concentrado no que ocorre quando um usuário pressiona um botão, enquanto um arquiteto está concentrado no que ocorre quando dez mil usuários pressionam um botão. ” - Paul R. Allen, Joseph J. Bambara –SCEA

## Mas orientação à objeto em PHP?

Não caia nessa de melhor linguagem, *pois a melhor linguagem é aquela que atende aos requisitos de seu projeto*, se você pode e consegue fazer isso de forma mais simples e prática em PHP, ou outra linguagem, escolha a que melhor te convém, não caia no modismo, o que pode ser melhor para outros, pode não ser pra você.

Aqui um pequeno depoimento da **MailChimp** a respeito do PHP ([fonte](https://blog.mailchimp.com/ewww-you-use-php/)).

> Usamos essa arquitetura para processar mais de trinta milhões de e-mails enviados por dezenas de milhares de usuários todos os dias, gerando dezenas de milhões de rejeições, confirmações, cliques, e unsubscribes que precisam ser tratados em tempo quase real. Nós processamos mais milhões de solicitações de API e milhões de inscrições e confirmações de todos os dias. Sobretudo, nós lidamos com bem mais de 500 milhões de page views dinâmicos por mês. Nossos sistemas de back-end executa milhões de trabalhos todos os dias, calculando estatísticas, consultar dados geográficos, e monitorando tudo em busca de mau comportamento e abuso. Isso apenas está ficando maior e maior à medida que crescemos em 500% ou mais a cada ano.

Também podemos citar os milhares de sites rodando Wordpress (PHP) e inclusive grande parte do Facebook. ([fonte](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/php-and-facebook/2356432130/))

## Resposta para a edição da pergunta

Conforme você editou sua pergunta deu cara de ser uma "nova" pergunta, o que basicamente deixou quase que todas as respostas fora do contexto.

O seu problema inicial era saber se armazenar configurações na $GLOBALS era ruim, já o seu problema atual após a edição é saber onde você pode armazenar essas configurações.

## Armazenando configurações de um site com segurança

É um par de problema/solução, existem alguns padrões que você pode utilizar para armazenar suas configurações com segurança.

**Solução 1**: Você pode criar um arquivo INI e armazenar fora da pasta pública de seu servidor, um diretório acima, assim quem tiver acesso somente à parte do famoso `public_http` de seu FTP não terá acesso à este arquivo.

**Pós**: O PHP fornece métodos nativos para a leitura de arquivos INI.

**Contra**: Não é possível alterar, pois provavelmente você não terá opção de gravação, e mesmo que tenha, não será seguro deixar seu arquivo com esses atributos.

**Solução 2**: Ler suas configurações normalmente através de um arquivo PHP em uma variável utilizando vetores, jogar para sua classe e então definir um valor nulo para a variável anterior.

**Pós**: Você não irá precisar das `$GLOBALS`, não será pesado, e as variáveis definidas no arquivo serão temporárias, já que você poderá jogar tudo isso para sua classe e inutilizar a variável anterior definindo um valor nulo.

**Contras**: Basicamente nenhum contra nesse método, você apenas precisa ter o cuidado na hora de anular a variável, no caso sua classe deve ter lido primeiro antes de definir um valor nulo.

Basicamente o seu problema está na hora de "ler" essas configurações, e não na forma que você as trata ou como as isola, se já está usando `OOP`, não há absolutamente nenhum motivo para usar `$GLOBALS`

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela resposta, mas eu já estou utilizando `OOP`, e já tinha as classes para ler as configurações, o meu problema é mesmo onde armazenar esses dados. E sim, sou a única a trabalhar nesse projeto, porque estou pegando num trabalho antigo e estou colocando tudo em classes pra poder usar quando quiser sem ter que reescrever as funções.

Comment: A minha classe também já injeta configurações.

Comment: Realizei alterações na resposta, porém confesso que realmente sua pergunta ficou muito diferente da original, deixando as outras perguntas com a resposta meio "sem nexo".

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma diretriz na qual diga como devemos projetar o sistema.

Por isso, não podemos dizer que está certo ou errado armazenar tais dados na variável `$GLOBALS`.

Todavia, há uma preocupação referente ao consumo de recursos desnecessários.

Exemplo prático

```
$GLOBALS = array(
    'foo1' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo2' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo3' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo4' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo5' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo6' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo7' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo8' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo9' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    'foo10' = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
);
```

Suponha que esse array seja bem maior e normalmente é o que acontece.

Por quê portar em todas as páginas, todos esses dados?

Imagine uma página que invoque uma função que necessita somente de "foo10".  Nenhum outro dado desse array imenso será usado. Porém, estão todos lá ocupando espaço na memória.

Algo mais econômico é carregar os dados somente quando realmente necessitar.

Exemplo

**foo10.php**

```
<?php
return array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

**pagina.php**

```
<?php
$foo10 = include 'foo10.php';
```

Isso é suficiente, organizado, simples e leve.

Permite também que o aplicativo seja escrito de forma modular. Ou seja, torna possível a re-usabilidade das funções para aplicativos de lógica de negócios diversas.

**Performance**

Obviamente, é insignificante o custo com performance em sistemas de baixo volume de acesso, porém, o que importa aqui é que mesmo num sistema pequeno, você tem um aplicativo com códigos organizados. Se não faz diferença na performance, então por que não escrever de uma forma mais organizada?

No entanto, o sistema não precisa chegar a volume de tráfego titânico como facebook, youtube, google, entre outros, para começar a apresentar problemas de performance.

Um volume pequeno de 10 mil acessos únicos por dia já torna as micro-otimizações perceptíveis e, o assunto do qual falamos aqui tem uma significância muito maior do que uma micro-otimização.

Há um custo de performance no uso de include também, o qual pode ser até mais danoso do que se os dados estivessem todos num array.

Contudo, podemos resolver isso criando estruturas de cache de compilação. Não estou falando no uso de Memcache, APC e coisas do gênero. Podemos construir estruturas de cache inteligente usando puramente os recursos nativos padrão do PHP. Claro que isso exige muito trabalho, mas compensa no final.

Os caches de compilação tornam um aplicativo mais de 800% veloz. Isso significa que os gargalos de performance serão sentidos quando o volume estiver em 50 ou 60 mil acessos únicos por dia e, isso é um volume relativamente alto.

A grande maioria dos desenvolvedores de sistemas não possuem esse tipo de preocupação por motivos diversos, mas no geral é por achar desnecessário preocupar-se com otimizações. No primeiro problema com performance entram em desespero ou, por comodidade apelam para loadbalance, cluster, mirrors. Enfim, estruturas que aumentam significativamente o custo com infra-estrutura e manutenção.

Abandonar toda a estrutura, trocando por outra tecnologia não é algo muito inteligente a menos que seja algo muito defasado, inviável de continuar usando e, esse não é o caso do PHP.

**O PHP é tão fraquinho e pobre como dizem?**

Sempre desconfie quando alguém disser que PHP não é bom para alto volume de dados e "isso" ou "aquilo".

Por muitos anos, nós programadores PHP sofremos com preconceito, sendo taxados de amadores por usarmos uma linguagem fracamente tipada e que "permite total libertinagem" no desenvolvimento de aplicativos. Realmente o preconceito era bastante forte até 2007 e vem diminuindo drasticamente desde então.

Esse preconceito caiu como mito quando o facebook declarou publicamente que ainda utiliza o PHP e MySQL. Apesar de já existirem na época diversos outros exemplos de sistemas de alto volume de dados rodando sob PHP.

Ao invés de trocar de tecnologia, apenas aperfeiçoaram o que já estavam usando.

Portanto, evite acreditar no mito de que projeto grande tem que ser feito com tecnologias grandes, caras e pesadas como JAVA e Oracle (apenas exemplo). Hoje em dia isso é tão batido que soa ridículo.

**Por quê o PHP é o mais criticado?**

Simplesmente por ser o mais popular. Estima-se que esteja presente em mais de 85% dos sistemas web no mundo todo.

Há também as críticas maldosas de cunho comercial. Um concorrente quer vender o seu peixe e como não consegue vencer por méritos dignos, apela para a baixaria com calúnias e espalhando inverdades.

**Bom senso**

Como sempre, deve prevalecer o bom senso e discernimento.

Exemplo, para quê usar um framework, por menor e econômico que seja, para simplesmente montar um site de 3 páginas estáticas e um formulário de contato com 3 campos?

Um simples $_POST[] e mail() já resolve o trabalho.

Enfim, as técnicas, ferramentas e conceitos devem ser aplicados conforme o caso.

O conceito final depende muito do nível de experiência dos envolvidos no projeto. É isso que difere um profissional senior do amador, no âmbito técnico.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Fiquei interessado também pela parte de "estruturas de cache de compilação". Você poderia me providenciar um link onde eu possa ler a respeito? Grato.

Comment: +1 E acho que seria legal que quem votou negativo justificasse...

Comment: Olha aí nossas perguntas sendo negativadas sem motivos novamente.

Comment: Tecnicamente, o motivo dos negativos pode ser pelo comentário extra sobre o uso do PHP e MySQL pelo facebook. Não mencionei que o facebook utiliza uma versão modificada de ambos pelo simples fato disso ser do conhecimento dos programadores PHP. Achei desnecessário colocar isso. Além do mais,  estenderia o assunto para fora do foco da pergunta. Mas algumas pessoas que negativam preferem não comentar.

Comment: As "estruturas de cache de compilação" mencionadas seria algo como uso de APC?

Comment: @utluiz, na resposta está descrito que não usa-se APC, Memcache e afins para tais estruturas de cache de compilação. Contudo, não quer dizer que tais recursos sejam desnecessários. Quer dizer apenas que é possível criar cache de compilação usando os recursos nativos padrão do PHP, otimizando a performance acima de 500%.

Comment: @Daniel Hum... então você estava se referindo a salvar o opcode? Desculpe a confusão, mas dada a nova pergunta sobre o tema, fiquei curioso pois nunca ouvi o termo dessa forma. Queria saber exatamente do que se tratava.

Comment: Também não faz uso do opcache. É realmente algo bem simples e quando usado em conjunto com opcode, memcache, apc, etc, aumenta ainda mais a performance. O ponto chave dessa técnica é eliminar os "includes" ao máximo possível. Claro que não é somente isso. É apenas um exemplo da lógica base dessa técnica. Um simples "include" ocupa processos dispendiosos. Tinha lido sobre o consumo dos includes num artigo há muitos anos atrás, acho que há mais 9 anos, e fiquei curioso e testei. Realmente consomem processos demais. Desde então passei a desenvolver técnicas usando o mínimo de recursos possível.