# O que são estruturas de cache de compilação?

Tags: php, desempenho, otimização, cache

Nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102402/globals-para-armazenar-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es) onde queria saber se devo armazenar configurações numa variável global `$GLOBALS`, recebi muito boas respostas, e havia uma que falava de uma coisa que eu não tinha sequer pensado, e decidi fazer essa pergunta para ver se alguém consegue me ajudar a entender melhor.

> - O que são estruturas de cache de compilação ?
> - Para que servem essas estruturas ?
> - São sempre necessárias ?
> - Como posso criar e usar essas estruturas ?

Investiguei também alguns termos e encontrei isso no [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster).

Eu li as regras do site, e sinceramente eu não sei se essa pergunta está ampla de mais, mas espero que esteja dentro das regras.

Comment: Considere "quebrar" essa perguntas em varias, para que não fique ampla demais como está.

Comment: Alguém vai te dar uma resposta, a pergunta é interessante. Mas você vai descobrindo que o que era simples e funcionava muito bem, de repente vai se tornando complicado, aí começa procurar soluções para arrumar os problemas causados pelas soluções que foram dadas anteriormente, e assim vai indo. Nem todo mundo é o Facebook. Que por sinal começou simples, quando ficou complexo, começaram trocar a linguagem. [KISS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple). Faça o site simples e ele não precisará das soluções complexas. Quando você começa "comprar" ferramentas não necessárias, não para mais.

Comment: Oi, o problema é isolado mesmo, quero apenas aprender mais sobre isso, caso eu venha a precisar um dia.

Comment: "Faça o site simples e ele não precisará das soluções complexas. Quando você começa "comprar" ferramentas não necessárias, não para mais." +1111111111

Comment: @gustavox é uma pena que em comentário não dá para dar um contexto melhor, mas você entendeu o principal :)

Comment: Eu não falei que vou usar isso já, eu quero saber apenas o que isso é e como funciona.

Comment: Ninguém se habilita?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O termo ***estruturas de cache de compilação*** provavelmente é apenas uma expressão usada na outra pergunta, não realmente um nome específico de alguma técnica ou tecnologia.

Entretanto, quando se fala em desempenho de uma linguagem interpretada como PHP, um dos maiores impactos no desempenho de uma aplicação (depois, é claro, de sanados os problemas arquiteturais) é o tempo que o próprio interpretador leva para carregar e analisar todo o código a cada requisição.

## Definindo o problema

Basicamente, vamos definir o problema principal da seguinte forma:

> Por padrão, a cada requisição, um novo interpretador PHP é instanciado, ele precisa carregar todos os arquivos fonte usados num sistema, interpretá-los e somente então executar o que está sendo solicitado.

Em tópicos, temos os seguintes impactos no desempenho:

1. Instanciação do interpretador PHP
2. Carregamento dos arquivos PHP
3. Interpretação e compilação em memória
4. Execução do sistema

Enquanto os programadores podem investir bastante no item #4, que é o que importa, os três primeiros são apenas um efeito colateral da linguagem e são repetidos vez após vez.

Para uma simples requisição isso pode não ser um problema, mas comece a multiplicar o número de usuários e logo o servidor estará mais ocupando com interpretação e leitura de arquivos PHP do que qualquer outra coisa.

Uma *startup* pode facilmente começar o desenvolvimento rápido de um sistema usando PHP. O problema, é que no momento que ela começar a escalar o número de clientes, ela vai estar gastando cada vez mais com hardware, manutenção e gerenciamento de servidores para sustentar a lentidão inerente da linguagem.

## Soluções

### #1. Interpretador PHP

No princípio havia o CGI. Neste modelo, um servidor como o Apache vai executar o interpretador do PHP a cada chamada, como se fosse uma chamada em linha de comando.

Vendo os problemas com isso, foram criadas algumas técnicas para deixar o interpretador PHP permanentemente em memória e assim evitar quase completamente o primeiro passo.

O interpretador pode ser incluído como um módulo do Apache, o que significa que o PHP fica instanciado junto com o servidor web. Devido há alguns problemas desse modelo, criou-se depois o modelo Fast CGI, onde o interpretador não fica mais no mesmo processo do servidor, mas permanece em memória num processo separado.

Não vou entrar em detalhes quanto aos [pós e contras](http://blog.layershift.com/which-php-mode-apache-vs-cgi-vs-fastcgi/) aqui, o importante é entender que ter o interpretador em memória aumenta muito o desempenho ao evitar a criação de um novo processo do PHP para cada requisição, que é como se cada usuário executasse um novo programa no servidor.

### #2 e #3. Carregamento e interpretação

Uma grande vantagem do PHP ler os arquivos a cada requisição é que você simplesmente precisa editá-los ou substituí-los e, *voi là*, o sistema foi atualizado "instantaneamente". Entretanto, isso também é ineficiente se precisa ser feito milhares de vezes por segundo.

Bem, até linguagens compiladas precisam ter os executáveis lidos do disco, mas além disso, o PHP ainda precisa interpretar os arquivos, o que significa analisar todos os caracteres, estruturas, verificar erros e, se tudo correr bem, gerar uma estrutura em memória para ser executada, que é conhecida como ***opcode***.

Para resolver isso, o caminho que muitas ferramentas usam é fazer *cache* dessas estruturas compiladas (*opcode cache*), de forma a evitar a repetição contínua tanto do carregamento do código-fonte (#2) quanto da compilação (#3).

*Opcode* é um código intermediário entre PHP e o código que realmente é executado, portanto não é tão rápido quanto código nativo, mas evita a interpretação do código-fonte original.

Se o *opcode* for gravado em disco, temos ainda o problema #2, onde ele precisa ser carregado a cada requisição, portanto é prática comum armazenar essas estruturas em memória. Dessa forma, depois da primeira requisição que inclua um determinado arquivo, aquele arquivo já vai estar disponível na memória compartilhada.

O problema com isso é que tudo deve ser feito novamente cada vez que o processo for reiniciado ou o sistema for atualizado.

#### Gerenciando *opcode cache*

Para colocar um arquivo PHP em memória, sem executá-lo, pode-se usar o comando [`opcache_compile_file(file)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-compile-file.php) da biblioteca [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

Entretanto, para evitar impactos no desempenho após a reinicialização ou atualização dos servidores, os arquivos devem ser carregados novamente após a inicialização do servidor e antes da primeira requisição.

Isso é particularmente importante quando você tem um *cluster* de servidores, isto é, vários servidores com o mesmo sistema que podem servir páginas para os usuários alternadamente.

Suponha que você tem dois servidores. Para atualizar o sistema, você para um deles fora do horário de pico, de forma que apenas o outro supra a demanda no momento. Você atualiza o sistema no servidor, realiza os testes necessários e "aquece" o sistema carregando todos os arquivos em cache. Finalmente, você coloca os servidor novamente no ar e vai para o próximo. Em tese, os usuários não devem perceber que houve uma atualização, nem vai haver degradação do desempenho nas primeiras requisições após a atualização.

É importante mencionar que há [várias ferramentas para gerenciar cache de opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache_.28APC.29), assim como outros tipos de cache. O [*Alternative PHP Cache* (**APC**)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php), por exemplo, é uma biblioteca de código-aberto que faz parte do projeto PHP e serve tanto para armazenar opcode quanto para armazenar valores arbitrários. Isso nos leva ao próximo tópico.

### #4. Fazendo cache na aplicação

Indo mais a fundo, é possível armazenar alguns objetos mais usados em cache, dessa forma, além de não precisar ler o arquivo e interpretá-lo, o sistema não precisa nem instanciar e carregar os dados.

Imagine que o sistema usa frequentemente coleções como:

- Lista de estados do país, que nunca muda;
- Lista de fornecedores, que muda talvez a cada mês;
- Lista de boletos em atraso, que é atualizado uma vez por dia;
- Configurações internas do sistema;
- Por aí vai...

## Juntando tudo

Todas as técnicas de cache e pré-aquecimento (*warming*) dos arquivos do sistema em memória, faz com que o processamento do servidor possa ser concentrado no que realmente importa, isto é, nas regras do sistema.

Em sistemas com muita carga, isto é, muitos acessos simultâneos, tais técnicas, alinhadas com [outras técnicas de desempenho](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/01/31/performance-tuning-overview/) e [outras estratégicas de caching](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/) podem economizar muito tempo e dinheiro, tanto em relação à aquisição de novos servidores, quanto ao gerenciamento e manutenção dos mesmos.

## Considerações

Não custa lembrar que cada otimização tem efeitos colaterais.

A complexidade de gerenciar caches, por exemplo, pode ser assustadora. Comportamentos bizarros podem ocorrer se isso for feito de forma errada, ainda mais pensando na possibilidade de código PHP em cache estar defasado.

Nunca se deve aplicar técnicas profundas de otimização e caching a não ser que seja necessário, caso contrário também vai se estar jogando dinheiro e tempo fora.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Já estava achando que ninguém ia responder! Vou deixar mais uns dias antes de conceder a recompensa, pra deixar com destaque, porque esta merece, muito boa resposta, principalmente pra quem tem o SOpt como principal fonte de aprendizado. Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @gustavox