# Variável global personalizada

Tags: php, variáveis, variáveis-globais

Nessa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102402/globals-para-armazenar-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es/102421?noredirect=1#comment209726_102421), eu expliquei que tava com algum medo de guardar minhas configurações na variável `$GLOBALS` porque ela transforma minhas configurações em valores globais, aí o cara me respondeu que não tinha problema, e depois me perguntou pelos comentários se eram globais como.

Criei esse exemplo pra explicar como eu gravo os valores e como pego eles, e aí talvez alguém aqui consiga me responder se devo evitar usar ela ou não. Também não sei se a pergunta é a mesma que a outra que fiz ontem, mas espero que não.

Nesse momento estou definindo minha variável assim:

```
$GLOBALS['configuracao'] = array(
    'banco'=>array(
        'nome'=>'proj3439',
        'tabela'=>'usuarios'
    ),
    'sessao'=>array(
        'tempo'=>24,
        'nomeSessao'=>'testeS'
    )
);
```

Ai se seu tentar imprimir o valor dele na tela, ele me apresenta o nome e os valores de todas as variáveis globais tipo `SERVER_ADDR`, `POST` e outros.

Agora, seu eu colocar o nome da minha configuração com o simbolo de variável e tentar imprimir o valor dele na tela, ele me retorna os valores que defini antes.

```
$GLOBALS['_CONFIG'] = array(
    'banco'=>array(
        'nome'=>'proj3439',
        'tabela'=>'usuarios'
    ),
    'sessao'=>array(
        'tempo'=>24,
        'nomeSessao'=>'testeS'
    )
);
```

Se eu tentar ler o valor dessa configuração aí do mesmo jeito como faço com o `POST`, ele vai me mostrar os valores que coloquei na variável:

```
print_r($_CONFIG);
```

Depois percebi também que se eu criar uma variável e colocar um valor nela, ela vai direitinho pra dentro da variável `$GLOBALS`.

```
$configuracao = "proj3439";
```

Essas configurações que coloquei aí em cima só aparecem quando inicio o *script* que define elas, eu chamo sempre esse *script* por isso tenho minhas configurações sempre carregadas. Quando elas são iniciadas eu consigo usar elas em qualquer lugar no meu *script*, mesmo dentro de classes e funções, ela parece uma variável normal, mas só que eu defini ela direto no `$GLOBALS`.

Tem algum problema definir minhas configurações no momento em que rodo o *script* ou mesmo nessa variável?

O povo consegue forjar dados que chegam pelo `$_GET` que também é uma global, e eu acabei criando uma global semelhante. Terei problemas de segurança?

Comment: O texto está perfeito, mas não entendi bem o objetivo da pergunta, ou seja, a frase final.

Comment: Desculpem, vou apagar essa pergunta, vi que ela não é muito diferente da outra. Vou usar o Google pra ajudar a preencher minha dúvida.

Comment: Pode deixar, só não entendi bem o que quer saber. Não importa se é diferente, pelo contrário, se é diferente, melhor ainda.

Comment: Definindo ela no `$GLOBALS` eu consigo usar ela de qualquer lugar, mesmo dentro de funções sem usar a palavra `global` a frente.

Comment: Quer saber a diferença e a vantagem de usar um ou outro?

Comment: O povo consegue forjar dados que chegam pelo `GET` que  também é uma global, e eu acabei criando uma global semelhante entende ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema de usar variáveis globais implicitamente não é grande, só que você perde a perspectiva que está lidando com globais.

Já viu nas [outras perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102402/101) que globais não é algo para ser abusado, para usar onde realmente precisa de [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). É fácil confundir as coisas quando lidamos com globais, mas existem casos para usar.

Então, apesar de poder acessar a variável diretamente evite fazer isto, crie uma convenção de sempre acessar globais de forma explícita dizendo que elas são globais.

Tem duas formas de fazer isto. Pelo *array* associativo [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) ou pela palavra chave [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Fazendo por qualquer um deles estará resolvendo um possível problema de escopo.

## $GLOBALS X global

Não havia diferença, mas parece que [na versão 5.4 começou ficar melhor usar a palavra-chave `global`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php#104666) do que a variável `$GLOBALS`. Semanticamente dá no mesmo, mas há um pequeno ganho usando a palavra-chave. Nada que vá mudar significativamente o desempenho, mas é um ganho.

Quando você chama a variável `$GLOBALS` pela primeira vez o PHP tem que pegar o nome de todas as globais e popular o `$GLOBALS` com elas, criando os membros do *array*, pois ele só passa a existir como variável quando é usado.

## Segurança

O `$GLOBALS` será usado não importando a sintaxe que use. E ele está seguro no servidor. Na verdade o `$_GET` e `$_POST` também estão. A insegurança que ouve falar são os dados que serão enviados para estas variáveis (que são globais também). [Você não tem controle sobre os dados que chegam de fora do servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101), mas quando eles estão lá dentro estão seguros.

No caso do que está no `$GLOBALS` você tem controle total sobre o conteúdo que está lá, não precisa se preocupar. O que está no `$_GET` você não sabe o que veio de fora, por isso dizem que você tem que validar o conteúdo. O problema não é a variável ser global e sim de onde vem o conteúdo dela, são coisas distintas.

Antes de usar qualquer recurso da linguagem não esqueça de ler a documentação e fazer como está fazendo, perguntar antes de usar, sempre que tiver dúvidas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Seu penúltimo parágrafo afirmou minha incerteza e me  poupou bastante tempo no Google, obg.