# Como fazer uma variável global em PHP?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, variáveis-globais

Tenho um login, e caso as credenciais estejam corretas ele abre um outro ficheiro PHP e queria que o nome da pessoa associado às credenciais usadas no login aparecesse numa label. Todas as informações estão guardadas numa BD.
Como faço para aceder aos valores guardados no primeiro ficheiro PHP?

O código do login é:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['senha']);

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password))
    {

        $query = "SELECT email, password, id_paciente FROM Paciente WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

    if ($result == 1) 
    {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                 $_SESSION['id_paciente'] = $row['id_paciente'];
                 $_SESSION['nome'] = $row['nome'];
                header("location: paciente_marcar_consulta_online.php");
        }
```

E queria passar o id_paciente para o ficheiro "paciente_marcar_consulta_online.php" em que depois fosse apresentar o nome desse id_paciente. Podem-me ajudar?

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49521/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102652/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar $_SESSION para guardar a váriavel nas Cookies!

No início do ficheiro, mesmo no topo digite este código:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Isto irá permitir você guardar variáveis em `$_SESSION`.
Em seguida acrescente isto no seu código:

```
if (!empty($email) && !empty($password))
    {

        $query = "SELECT email, password, id_paciente FROM Paciente WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

    if ($result == 1) 
    {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                $_SESSION['id_paciente'] = $row['nome_da_variavel'];
                header("location: paciente_marcar_consulta_online.php");
        }
```

Como pôde ver, apenas alterei a variável que você queria mandar, mas altere o nome se assim desejar.

Agora na página `paciente_marcar_consulta_online.php`, no início da página digite o mesmo código `<?php session_start(); ?>` e depois defina uma variável e vá buscar o valor enviado pela SESSION, ou seja

```
<?php $id_paciente = $_SESSION['id_paciente']; ?>
```

***Mais Informações***

Uma vez com o id do paciente, faça uma query para ir buscar os dados do paciente.

```
$query = "SELECT FROM Paciente WHERE id_paciente= '$id_paciente'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
```

Agora só falta imprimir o nome

```
<label><?=$row['nome']; ?></label>
```

Comment: mas como faço para numa label apresentar o nome associado na base de dados a esse id_paciente

Comment: Você vai exibir os dados com echo $_SESSION['nome']; mas lá no início quando você fizer o login do usuário, salve o nome dele também em uma variável de sessão .

Comment: @IsabelSousa Veja o que acrescentei

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho Tenho uma combobox que é preenchida pela base de dados e quando seleciono um nome, preenche o formulário respetivo. Eu guardo o id assim:                                                                                    
 'echo '<option value="'.$prod['txtid'].'">'.$prod['txtNome'].'</option>';'                 mas precisava de usar esse id para query delete, o único problema é que esse query está num ficheiro PHP que é chamado ao ficheiro principal onde está a combobox.