# O que é ortogonalidade?

Tags: terminologia

Dentro do contexto do desenvolvimento de software o que significa algo ser ortogonal?

Por que é importante segui-lo?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Algo é ortogonal em relação à alguma outra coisa se mudar algo nele não afetará nada nas outras coisas. Não existe uma relação de dependência.

É muito importante buscar a ortogonalidade sempre que possível. Imagine se um carro mudasse de direção quando você acelera. Ruim, né? No carro o acelerador e volante são ortogonais. Já num helicóptero não conseguiram fazer isso e para aumentar a velocidade tem que compensar outros controles para manter o helicóptero estável.

Também podemos falar em [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101). Se o seu código faz algo estanque, só relacionado a ele mesmo, ele é ortogonal, não possui efeitos colaterais. Se você tem que se preocupar com o que vai acontecer em outros lugares quando muda algo nele então ele não é ortogonal.

O que não é [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) não é ortogonal. Se não aplicou esse princípio, quando muda em um lugar tem que mudar nas suas repetições.

Ortogonalidade está relacionada não exclusivamente com o princípio do [SRP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101).

Uma linguagem de programação é uma das coisas mais complicadas de se fazer porque muita coisa não é ortogonal. Cada *feature* funciona bem sozinha, mas junto com todas as outras tem um monte de complicação quando há intersecção. Quando as *features* podem ser usadas em conjunto sem restrições e complicações ela é ortogonal.

É importante para gerenciar a complexidade, facilitar a manutenção e diminuir a necessidade de testes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: estava precisando fazer uma pergunta relacionada à efeito colateral (side-effect) justamente essa semana.

Comment: @durtto se não respondeu, com o que tem aqui, manda ver.

Answer (score 10):

Em desenvolvimento de software a definição de **ortogonalidade** é exatamente a mesma que a utilizada no âmbito matemático.

Na álgebra, diz-se ortogonais quando duas grandezas possuem o produto escalar (ou interno) igual a zero, **x** ⋅ **y** = 0. O cálculo do produto escalar pode ser resumido à **x** ⋅ **y** = x y cosθ, sendo θ o menor ângulo entre as duas grandezas. Para grandezas não nulas, diz-se ortogonais apenas quando cosθ vale 0, o que implica em θ igual a 90º. Por isso que, quando consideradas apenas duas grandezas, o conceito de ortogonalidade e perpedicularidade acabam se misturando.

Quando tratado de vetores, também pode-se calcular quanto a grandeza de um vetor influencia da grandeza de outro, isto é, calcula-se a **projeção** de uma grandeza sobre a outra e esse cálculo pode ser feito através de p<sub>roj</sub> = |**p**| cosθ, sendo θ novamente o menor ângulo entre as grandezas.

Assim, portanto, se duas grandezas são ortogonais, sabe-se que cosθ será nulo e, consequentemente, a projeção de grandeza sobre a outra também será nula.

Em termos menos técnicos, isso implica que pode-se alterar a magnitude de uma das grandezas sem alterar a magnitude das demais grandezas ortogonais a ela.

Quando relacionado ao desenvolvimento de software, pode-se traduzir a definição para como cada parte do código não possuir projeção sobre as demais partes, isto é, quando uma parte sofrer alteração, as demais partes do sistema não serão afetadas. Quando partes não são ortogonais, a projeção de uma sobre a outra é diferente de zero e, portanto, qualquer alteração feita em uma deve-se tomar o cuidado sobre como impactará nas outras.

Buscar desenvolver "orientado à ortogonalidade" tem várias consequências positivas, tal como a facilidade de manutenção, dado que uma [unidade de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878) sendo ortogonal ao resto da aplicação pode ser alterada sem a preocupação de como as alterações impactarão na aplicação inteira, desde que a ortogonalidade seja mantida.

Para uma visualização mais prática, podemos imaginar uma grandeza em X e outra em Y, ortogonais entre si, produzindo, juntas, a grandeza vermelha. É possível alterar individualmente as grandezas X e Y (através dos *ranges*) sem afetar a outra de forma a alterar o resultado como desejado.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const x = document.getElementsByName('x')[0];
const y = document.getElementsByName('y')[0];

function update() {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Desenha o eixo X:
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 300);
  context.lineTo(x.value, 300);
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 300);
  context.lineTo(0, 300 - y.value);
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 300);
  context.lineTo(x.value, 300 - y.value);
  context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.stroke();

  context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
}

x.addEventListener('change', update);
y.addEventListener('change', update);

update();
```

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <div>
    <label>X: <input type="range" name="x" value="100" min="0" max="300"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Y: <input type="range" name="y" value="100" min="0" max="300"></label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="half">
  <canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Em linguagem de programação, **ortogonalidade** significa que um conjunto relativamente pequeno de construções primitivas podem ser combinadas em um número pequeno de maneiras para construir as estruturas de controle e de dados de uma linguagem.

Na prática, uma linguagem ortogonal seria mais fácil de aprender e teria menos exceções. ***Porque cada exceção é uma construção que precisa ser aprendida para ser evitada***.
Alguns exemplos de falta de ortogonalidade (clássicos) em C:

- Um struct podem ser valores de retorno de uma função, mas vetores
  não.
- Um vetor pode ser valor de retorno se estiver encapsulado por um
  struct
- Um membro de um struct pode ser qualquer tipo de dado exceto
  void ou um struct do mesmo tipo.
- Um vetor pode ser de qualquer tipo exceto void.
- Todos os tipos de dados são passados por valor exceto vetores

Por outro lado, o excesso de ortogonalidade é prejudicial:

- Todas as instruções ( incluindo atribuições, if, while, etc) retornam valores e podem ser usado em expressões.
- Operações lógicas e aritméticas podem aparecer misturadas.

Answer (score -1):

– **ORTOGONALIDADE**

• Um conjunto relativamente pequeno de construções
primitivas pode ser combinado, em um número relativamente
pequeno de maneiras, para construir as estrutura de controle
e de dados da linguagem

• O significado de um recurso de linguagem ortogonal é livre
de contexto de sua aparência em um programa

**Importância**

• Torna a linguagem mais fácil de aprender

• Diminui as restrições de programação

• Muita ortogonalidade também pode causar problemas

• Simplicidade

– Combinação de um número relativamente pequeno de
construções primitivas

– Uso limitado do conceito de ortogonalidade
[edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/1957769/mod_resource/content/3/Linguagens%20de%20Programação%20-%202014%20aula1.pdf](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/1957769/mod_resource/content/3/Linguagens%20de%20Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20-%202014%20aula1.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

Em ciência da computação, ortogonalidade no projeto de linguagem de programação é a capacidade de usar vários recursos da linguagem em combinações arbitrárias com resultados consistentes. O número de conceitos primitivos independentes foi minimizado para que a linguagem seja fácil de descrever, aprender e implementar. Por outro lado, esses conceitos foram aplicados "ortogonalmente" a fim de maximizar o poder expressivo da linguagem enquanto tentava evitar superfluidades deletérias.
REF.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality

Comment: "em combinações arbitrárias com resultados consistentes", consegue detalhar melhor essa parte? Ficou bem confusa essa afirmação. E o que são "conceitos primitivos independentes"? E o que seria "superfluidades deletérias"?

Comment: Perdão, @Woss. A tradução pode ter ficado um pouco deficiente em relação ao texto original.
Texto original: "Orthogonality in programming language design is the ability to use various language features in arbitrary combinations with consistent results".