# Quando usar classes locais no Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, scope

Eu aprendi que é possível declarar classes dentro de blocos como métodos, por exemplo:

```java
void exemplo() {
    class teste {

    }
}
```

Mas quando classes locais vem a ser útil?

Comment: Declarar classe dentro de método eu nunca vi. A não ser que seja alguma versão nova do Java, acredito que se refere a classes internas (inner classes). Mas elas não são declaradas dentro de métodos e sim dentro de outras classes.

Comment: @Piovezan Na verdade isso existe há muito tempo (veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428186) de 2010, por exemplo). Mas como é pouco usado, muita gente nem sabe que é possível (eu particularmente nunca uso porque nunca lembro...)

Comment: @hkotsubo Nossa :) vivendo e aprendendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma questão de [escopo e visibilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). Se você terá um objeto definido por essa classe usado-o apenas dentro deste método por que outras partes do código deveriam poder ter acesso a esta classe e possivelmente usá-la de forma inadequada, poluindo o escopo mais geral (lembrando que diversas ferramentas sugerem o que pode usar e poderia sugerir essa classe em algum contexto que não pode usá-la só porque a classe foi definida no escopo mais geral)?

Existe uma regra básica que você deve declarar qualquer coisa no menor escopo possível que funcione bem, assim melhora a legibilidade encapsulando a funcionalidade só onde ela precisa ser usada, quanto mais ela é visível mais pode dar confusão com alguma outra coisa, o código fica menos [ortogonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101).

Algumas linguagens preferem usar um tipo anônimo ou tupla para lidar com isso, até porque a utilidade é mais rara, se fizer certo, se só precisa de uma estrutura ali não existe muito motivo de criar um tipo real nomeado e completo só para isto, certo?