# Em programação orientada a objetos, uma classe abstrata, os seus métodos são estáticos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas, métodos-estáticos

Acredito que a pergunta serve para qualquer linguagem de programação.

Em Programação orientada a objetos, uma classe abstrata, os seus métodos são estáticos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não. O que define uma classe abstrata é basicamente a existência de métodos abstratos, ou seja, sem implementação. Estes métodos são de instância normalmente, mas assim como ocorre na interface, ele não tem código e obriga a classe derivada dela criar uma implementação.

Nada impede de existir zero métodos abstratos, ela continua podendo ser abstrata, mas não faz sentido. Quantos e quais métodos serão abstratos depende do problema, não tem regra.

Uma classe abstrata obviamente não pode ser instanciada diretamente já que a implementação não está completa, mesmo que esteja, só o fato de ter dito que é abstrata já impede, afinal se tem essa assinatura é porque no futuro pode estar incompleta (ainda que isso possa gerar outros problemas, mas não vem ao caso).

Uma classe abstrata, tanto quanto uma normal pode ter métodos estáticos. Como isso não tem relação com herança (eles não são herdados), tanto faz. Métodos estáticos não podem ficar sem implementações porque eles sempre podem ser chamados de forma direta. Os conceitos são [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101).

Os detalhes podem mudar em cada linguagem, mas o básico é universal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).