# DRY x Ortogonalidade

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Li aqui uma resposta à pergunta: [O que é ortogonalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101), nela dizia que o que "não é DRY não é ortogonal", então fiquei em dúvida nas seguintes questões:

1. Qual é a relação entre ambos?
2. Tudo que é DRY é ortogonal, mas tudo que é ortogonal é DRY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São conceitos bem distintos embora possam ser confundidos em cenários específicos.

Existem coisas que são DRY e não são ortogonais e vice versa, a única situação que que podemos afirmar é o que foi colocado na resposta lá, algo não DRY não consegue ser ortogonal, as outras combinações são possíveis.

Se você não cumpre o DRY a ortogonalidade está quebrada porque tem mais de um lugar onde a mesma coisa acontece, se você alterar um e não no outro dá resultado diferente do que seria esperado.

Se manter o DRY terá canonicidade daquilo, mas pode ser em algo não ortogonal até porque pode estar comparando com algo diferente. Você pode ter um local único que cuida de tudo que envolve juros de mercado, e uma alteração ali vai alterar *outros* dados em outros lugares, o que quebra a ortogonalidade. O contrário acontece de forma simétrica.

Lembre-se que DRY é sobre a mesma coisa, ortogonalidade é sobre coisas distintas.

Pegando o exemplo do helicóptero, não existe dois lugares para você acelerar, existem dois ações necessárias para acelerar corretamente, por isso chamei de não DRY, isto é mais não ortogonal do que não DRY, mas não deixa de ser.