# Organização de classes

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Preciso criar um sistema de *posts*.

Estou com dificuldades em estudar classe e estou com dúvida em qual das duas formas utilizar:

```
class publicarPost {}
class excluirPost {}
class curtir {}
```

ou

```
class Post {
 function publicarPost(){}
 function excluirPost(){}
 function curtir(){}
}
```

Ou alguma forma com o código mais bonito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma coisa que muitos não entendem sobre orientação a objeto é que o paradigma é sobre organizar o código para **atender requisitos**.

Como não tem os requisitos na pergunta não temos como dizer o que é certo. Seguir receita de bolo e fazer sempre igual não é orientação a objeto. Na verdade se receitas de bolo podem ser aplicadas de forma tão simples provavelmente este código não deveria estar sendo escrito.

Claro que vendo os dois exemplos não é difícil dizer que o primeiro provavelmente não é necessário, mas não posso afirmar. Pra falar a verdade em PHP muito do que se faz em OOP não é necessário, afinal são só *scripts*. O exemplo da outra resposta provavelmente não é necessário ser tão sofisticado.

Mas tem casos que você precisa de estratégias diferentes de publicação, exclusão, curtição e outras ações para o mesmo tipo, mas em objetos diferentes. Em algumas casos uma herança pode ser uma boa, em outras a composição pode ser melhor e aí o primeiro exemplo faz sentido para usar em conjunto com o segundo. Mas isso provavelmente é algo mais avançado, e novamente, provavelmente uma arquitetura não tão necessário para *scripts*.

Eu sempre recomendo para iniciantes começar do começo, OOP não deveria ser uma prioridade. Ninguém começa uma casa pelo acabamento, a não ser no nosso ramo, por isso pedreiros iniciantes costumam ganhar mais que programadores "experientes".

Comment: Por se tratar de "só scripts", **na grande maioria**, usamos a OO mais para organização de código do que necessidade ? Um motivo mais particular do que funcional ? (Salvo, realmente os casos que necessitam de trabalhar com dezenas de informações iguais, onde se torna essencial a OO) Sempre vejo seus comentários sobre OO, e parece uma visão bem além do que geralmente se encontra, onde a OO é usada sem necessidade... gostaria muito de entender essa sua visão pela experiencia que tem, pois com certeza seria útil para todos nós !

Comment: @RBZ na verdade não sei porque usam OOP em *scripts*. O *script*  é sua organização. Códigos efêmeros não precisa de tanta organização assim. Na verdade eu acho que quase não há visão sobre OO por aí. Tem algumas raras pessoas que manjam muito (não é o meu caso), tem pessoas muito respeitadas que não manjam tanto quanto as pessoas acham, suas ideias n]ao fazem sentido, mas como as outras não sabem nada, acham que faz. Eu estou nesses últimos meses/anos tentando formar uma posição mais sólida e talvez até faça algo maior sobre o assunto. O que te garanto é que OOP é usada mais do que deveria...

Comment: ...e a maioria ou sabe pouco sobre o assunto, ou sabe coisas de forma bem errada (era meu caso há pouco tempo, mesmo usando isto por 30 anos), ou ainda sequer sabem o que OOP significa, elas só querem fazer o que todo mundo diz que é bom. Se pesquisar minhas respostas (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20%5borienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos%5d) sobre o assunto já terá uma noção do que penso.

Comment: Se achar que nada responde o que quer saber, faça uma pergunta, com muito cuidado, por que ela tem grande chance de ser ampla. Informe nela que quer ajuda para melhorá-la e não deixar cair em ampla, peça ajuda no chat. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277179/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104346/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101

Comment: Vou ler com toda certeza ! Eu por estar na área de programação mais por hobby do que outra coisa, faço muita pesquisa e nelas se vê realmente diversas formas de utilização. Agora nesse tempo participando do SOpt vendo seus dizeres tendo seus 30 anos de experiência (ainda mantendo humildade em dizer que não manja muito rs) é algo que chamou muito a atenção e realmente estarei esperando  sua posição quanto ao isso ! E parabéns por compartilhar !

Comment: Tenho 35 em TI, 30 de OOP (está quase fazendo 30). Quase tudo que ensina OO é errado, fraco, incompleto, dúbio, contraditório e eu demorei para perceber. Tive várias fases de amar e odiar OOP, agora estou na fase boa a aprendendo como realmente o paradigma é e pode ser útil, à caminho da eliminação do meu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect (no assunto) e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome (que acho que nunca tive forte). O DK é uma desgraça pq é muito fácil cair nele e muito difícil perceber que caiu,portanto muito difícil de sair (quase leva à depressão:)

Comment: "a ignorância gera confiança com mais frequência do que o conhecimento" sensacional! Vou ler tudo com tempo, e o que conseguir colocar como dúvida relevante e direta, vou postar !