# Como armazenar configurações de um site?

Tags: php, configuração, armazenamento

Pretendo desenvolver um site que possui algumas opções de configuração, por exemplo:

- Manter o logotipo padrão ou personalizado
- Permitir registro de novos usuários
- Autorizar comentários de anônimos em postagens

Como estas configurações devem ser mantidas? Lembrando que existe um painel de controle onde o usuário pode alterá-las.

Comment: Não é a mesma pergunta, porém eu já perguntei isso a um tempo atrás. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98960/%C3%89-recomendado-o-uso-de-constantes-pra-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-projeto-em-php - Talvez possa ser útil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende do jeito que precisa.

A forma mais simples é colocar estas informações em variáveis globais ou encapsulada de alguma forma (um *array*, uma classe, etc.). Isso costuma funcionar bem se não puder ser alterado pelos usuários. Até dá para deixar o usuário alterar, mas não vale a complicação para fazer certo.

Se o usuário (diferente do programador ou do instalador da aplicação) pode configurar isto, conforme indicado na pergunta, então seria melhor armazenar em outro lugar. Pode ser um arquivo simples, ou melhor ainda seria colocar em um banco de dados, especialmente se a aplicação já usa um.

## O que eu faria

Em geral uma tabela simples com uma coluna para cada configuração possível costuma ser suficiente. A maioria das colunas serão booleanas, mas nada impede de ter qualquer informação configurável.

Se quiser generalizar mais dá para criar uma tabela que permite que o usuário defina suas próprias configurações. Claro que isso ajuda pouco se o código não souber o que fazer com elas.

Uma tabela simples basta para a configuração geral. Se tiver configurações mais especializadas, por usuário por exemplo, tem que ter um coluna indicando a quem pertence aquele valor específico, e a aplicação precisa saber ler isso de acordo com o usuário.

Essa é a parte importante para armazenar. Depois tem que pensar se vale a pena ter algumas otimizações para evitar acesso ao banco de dados toda vez que precisa de uma dessas configurações. Tem que pensar se deve ter uma forma para abstrair o acesso e permitir que no futuro o método de armazenamento possa ser trocado.

Enfim, tem bastante coisa que precisa ser pensada. Mas a pergunta não tem detalhes, só posso responder em linhas gerais.

Answer (score 3):

Eu costumo criar uma classe `app_config`, e sua instância logo na index da aplicação com o diretório atual e indico um arquivo de configuração `config.ini.php` com as configurações, em seu conteúdo eu coloco:

```
;<?php
;die("Se quiser, coloque uma mensagem de erro aqui caso o usuário tente acessar esse arquivo");
;/*

[db]
usuario=user;
senha=pass;
host=localhost;
database=db;
chatset=utf8;
```

*PS: Eu utilizei o exemplo de banco de dados que é o mais genérico possível, há casos que você irá precisar usar outro tipo de autenticação no seu banco e não irá armazenar as senhas assim, tudo depende do seu projeto, já se for algo simples, não haverá problema. Já explico o porquê do `.ini.php`*

Criando o arquivo `.ini.php` e colocando esses comentários acima é útil quando você ou seu cliente utilize uma hospedagem compartilhada e não tiver como colocar fora do `public_html` do projeto, não haverá risco do usuário baixar o `.ini.php`, mesmo não contendo nenhuma regra no `htaccess`.

E aqui a classe `app_config` para ler o arquivo.

```
class app_config
{
    private $ini;
    private $projeto_dir;

    /** método construtor, recebe o caminho completo do sistema para o 
        arquivo ini, e então verifica sua existência **/
    public function __construct($arquivo, $projeto_dir)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->ini = parse_ini_file($arquivo,true);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            die('Não foi possível encontrar o arquivo de configuração solicitado, a execução não poderá continuar');
        }
        $this->projeto_dir = $projeto_dir;
    }

    /** 
      * Retorna o valor da sessão e parâmetro solicitado
      *
      * Requer um arquivo de configuração válido 
      *  
      * @name get
      * @access public
      * @return string 
    **/
    private function get($sessao,$parametro)
    {
        return $this->ini[$sessao][$parametro];
    }

    /** 
      * Retorna o usuário do banco de dados
      *
      * @return string
    **/
    public function get_db_usuario() 
    { 
        return $this->get('db','usuario'); 
    }

    /** 
      * Retorna a senha do banco de dados
      *
      * @return string
    **/
    public function get_db_senha() 
    { 
        return $this->get('db','senha'); 
    }
}
```

Assim quando for preciso, você pode injetar sua instância em alguma classe que utilize seus métodos.

```
// A instância da index pega o diretório do projeto com dirname(__FILE__)
    $config = new app_config('local/para/sua/config/config.ini.php', dirname(__FILE__));
    $projeto = new projeto_exemplo($config);
```

Dentro da sua classe que você pretende injetar essas configurações, tenha um atributo do tipo `app_config` para receber o objeto que vamos passar por parâmetro.

Essa técnica de injetar o que você precisa em uma classe é conhecida como **injeção de dependência**.

Dentro do exemplo, poderemos então chamar os métodos do `app_config`.

```
$db = $this->config->get_db_usuario();
```

A classe que eu te passei é só um esboço, a minha é enorme e muito específica ao meu projeto, porém essa é a lógica que eu utilizo.

**Vantagens**

- Não cria objetos globais.
- Não utiliza constantes que poderão ser visíveis à todo o projeto.
- É completamente orientado à objeto.
- Utiliza o encapsulamento.
- Pode ler arquivos .ini fora e dentro do `public_html`
- Dependendo do seu projeto, pode ser reutilizado.

**Desvantagens**

- É mais trabalhoso que uma simples constante global, porém, trabalho duro nesse caso é bem-vindo.

Você também pode definir métodos set/get para pegar informações do banco de dados, basta implementar métodos que façam isso diretamente nessa classe.