# O uso exagerado de constantes pode afetar o desempenho do sistema?

Tags: php, constantes

Eu uso bastantes `constantes` no php para que guarde informações para configurar o sistema

> Exemplo:

```php
define('_CONFIG_SERVER','PC\SQLEXPRESS');
define('_CONFIG_DATA','Database');
define('_CONFIG_NAME','localhost');
define('_CONFIG_LANGUAGE_DEFAULT','pt-BR');
```

Eu utilizo bastante mesmo...Isto pode diminuir o *desempenho* do sistema???

Eu encontrei um [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98960/%C3%89-recomendado-o-uso-de-constantes-pra-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-projeto-em-php) parecido, mas não responde a minha pergunta que no caso é a questão do desempenho!

Comment: Acho que mencionar isto [Até que ponto a otimização prematura é um problema?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29507/at%C3%A9-que-ponto-a-otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-prematura-%C3%A9-um-problema), pode ser útil.

Comment: Kkkkkk gostei do texto, no momento estou apenas estudando para só mais pra frente iniciar um projeto...no caso a otimização prematura é apenas quando se está feito e tenta otimiza-ló? ou se eu utilizar antes de tudo, serve o mesmo exemplo? @Inkeliz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim pode, mas "uso exagerado" seria definir *milhares* de constantes em cada carregamento de página. Você está definindo 20, 50, talvez até 100? Então provavelmente é irrelevante e tentar mudar isso seria micro-otimização, existem inúmeras outras coisas infinitamente mais importantes para a performance do seu código que algo assim.

Caso você realmente esteja fazendo algo muito louco com toneladas de constantes pode tentar dar uma olhada [nesta extensão](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php) cujo propósito é justamente otimizar definição em massa de constantes.