# O que são Objetos Deus?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, objetos

Estava lendo a documentação do [WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/), e me deparei com a seguinte linha:

> ### Avoid God Objects
>
> [God Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) are objects that know or do too much. The point of object-oriented programming is to take a large problem and break it into smaller parts. When functions do too much, it’s hard to follow their logic, making bugs harder to fix. Instead of having massive functions, break them down into smaller pieces.

No trecho diz: "Objetos Deus são objetos que sabem muito ou fazem muito". Não entendi o conceito do mesmo, mesmo após ler em outros sites.

O que é um Objeto Deus e por que devemos evitar usá-los?

Comment: Acho que deve ser um objeto relativo uns pensam que existem outros, alguns teem a certeza que foi ele que nos instanciou, outros duvidam se e esse objeto ou outro, muitos negam a existencia do mesmo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

God Object não é muito além do que está dito aí. Esses objetos são capazes de fazer muitas coisas, ele não seguem o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101). Muitas vezes a pessoa os cria sem perceber que isto está acontecendo, em exagero é possível que o objeto seja capaz de fazer tudo da aplicação ou de boa parte dela, mas é mais comum ver casos que tem duas ou mais responsabilidades, ainda que assim em pequena medida também seja um exagero de chamar um "objeto deus".

A questão é que alguns objetos possuem naturalmente uma responsabilidade única e ser muita coisa. Um objeto `Carro` costuma ser um objeto assim, ele é um objeto coeso e que tem muitas responsabilidades, mas elas estão encapsuladas em outros objetos menores e não estão vinculados de forma direta ao objeto do carro. É preciso cuidado para classificar objetos como deuses em qualquer situação.

Em geral o pessoal dá esse nome como *antipattern* para objetos que sabem muito sobre outros objetos, mas nem sempre é fácil definir o que é muito. O exemplo do carro, claro que ele não precisa saber dos detalhes de cada parte do carro, mas ele precisa conhecer vários pontos de contato com esses objetos. Claro, tem [técnicas para ajudar combater isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101), a composição é uma delas, embora alguns puristas podem achar que não.

O oposto dele é o "código ravióli" onde tem um monte de pequenas classes fáceis de entender sozinhas, mas na hora que vai usar juntas fica uma confusão enorme e a pessoa se perde.

As pessoas olham para *antipatterns* para serem evitados com uma praga, mas não é bem assim, muitas vezes eles servem a um propósito e evitar um deles implica em cair em outro, não tem como fugir de algo ruim, então você escolhe o que é melhor para aquele caso. Muitos exemplos que eu vi de solução resolvia um problema e causava outro.

É um dos muitos conceitos que você só aprende usar certo com a prática e se tiver bom senso crítico, então ele serve de guia para saber que existe algo assim, que é um erro fazer algo do tipo sem um motivo, mas achar o ponto exato de aplicação não tem nada escrito que ajude. Sem muita experiência vendo os problemas que dão em manutenção é complicado seguir certo. E sem domínio do domínio que está resolvendo o problema é fácil cometer erros.

Ele deve ser evitado porque costuma manter [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) ruim (não vou entrar em detalhes aqui). E por isso pode causar mais [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101).

Note que OOP clássico sempre incentivou o uso desses objetos, existe um grupo que vai contra isso, e essas pessoas nem imaginam que estão fazendo algo diferente do nome que estão falando. Para evitar objetos deuses há um tendência de quebra do encapsulamento.

[Veja mais](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

A meu ver um god object é uma classe/objeto que possui muitas responsabilidades, comumente associada a frase "knows too much or does too much". Normalmente, o god object, possui um acoplamento e dependência tão fortes, que qualquer modificação em sua estrutura pode afetar todo uma aplicação. Dai ser considerado um anti-padra e o porque de ter que ser evitado

Answer (score 7):

O *God Object* (ou Objeto Deus) é uma porção do código (que pode ser uma classe ou outro item) que sabe muito ou faz muita coisa. Nos piores casos, ele sabe e faz muita coisa. Também pode ser conhecido pelo termo *[God Class](https://wiki.c2.com/?GodClass)*.

Normalmente ele pode ser identificado na aplicação quando começa atender uma ou mais das seguintes características (algumas mais subjetivas que outras):

- Dificuldade de entender a responsabilidade dela; ela tem várias. Isto viola um princípio da área de programação amplamente difundida e conhecida como [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (*Single Responsibility Principle*).
- Dificuldade em fazer testes para ela
- Manutenção difícil; as alterações nela refletem em outras porções do código, quebrando facilmente seu funcionamento.
- Tem muitas linhas de código
- Código de difícil leitura

Quer ver como se parece um *God Object*? Vamos a um [exemplo](https://sergeyzhuk.me/2017/03/11/oop-god-objects/):

```cs
public static class EmployeeManager
{
    public static void HireEmployee(Employee employee) {...}
    public static void TerminateEmployee(int employeeID) {...}
    public static void EditEmployee(Employee employee) {...}
    public static void AddVacationTime(int employeeID, DateTime vacationDate) {...}
    public static void CancelVacationTime(int employeeID, DateTime vacationDate) {...}
    public static void AddAddress(int employeeID, Address address) {...}
    public static void RemoveAddress(int employeeID, int addressID) {...}
    public static void GiveBonus(int employeeID, decimal bonus) {...}
    public static void AssignEquipment(int employeeID, Equipment equipment) {...}
    public static void GiveRaise(int employeeID, decimal amount) {...}
    public static void DockPay(int employeeID, decimal amount) {...}
    public static void AddSchedule(int employeeID, Schedule schedule) {...}
    public static void AddPhoneNumber(int employeeID, string phoneNumber) {...}
}
```

Esta classe, claramente, faz muitas coisas que ela poderia delegar para outras classes.

As formas de refatorar esta classe são inúmeras, mas poderíamos começar tendo uma classe `VacationManager`, `AddressManager`, etc. Poderíamos também ir mais fundo ainda e criar vários objetos representando a regra de negócio acima, criando objetos `Address`, `PhoneNumber`, etc.

Enfim, já teríamos um cenário muito melhor que o apresentado no código acima. Esta granularidade permitiria identificar mais facilmente as responsabilidades do código, permitiria uma manutenção mais simples e com menos riscos de efeitos colaterais, permitiria testes menores e mais fáceis de implementar, entre outras vantagens.

Comment: Bela resposta. +1 para ir para cima.